# I can't figgure out how input for LSTM is supposed to look

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, lstm, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

So I'm trying to implement an LSTM for sound classification with pytorch/pytorch lightning and basically feed it FFT spectrograms and MFCC transforms with 13 filters as the feaures. Everything is padded and in the end the data module basically feeds the model two tensors of shape 10, 2599, 201 and 10, 2599, 13(10 is the batch size and each batch is a slice of the time series).

I get the following error:
"stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [10, 2599, 201] at entry 0 and [10, 2599, 13] at entry 1",
when fitting the model. Is there no way to use the stacked MFCC and the spectrogram as individual features and keep each time series slice 2d without making them the same size? The MFCC has 13 columns for each filter and the spectrogram one for each frequency band.
(I don't know exactly what part of the code would be needed to recieve help so I'll provide as needed)